# Nest.js Auth Guard JWT Authentication returns 401 everytime

Tags: authentication, jwt, nestjs

Im testing my endpoints with Insomnia even though I provide the JWT token I get Unauthorized 401 as a response, here is my AuthService

The singIn function works I get my Token but if I try a other request like getUsers I get Unauthorized

In Insomnia I have a Bearer token where I put my Token, I get Unauthorized  tho

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars */
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';
import { User } from '../entities/user.entity';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import bcrypt from 'bcrypt';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Repository } from 'typeorm';
import { compare } from 'bcrypt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(
    private userService: UserService,
    @InjectRepository(User)
    private userRepository: Repository<User>,
  ) {}

  async validateUser(
    username: string,
    pass: string,
  ): Promise<Omit<User, 'password'> | null> {
    const user = await this.userService.findOneByUsername(username);
    if (user && user.password === pass) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
      const { password, ...result } = user;
      return result;
    }
    return null;
  }
  async getHashedPassword(username: string): Promise<string> {
    const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ where: { username } });
    return user ? user.password : null;
  }
  async signIn(username: string, password: string): Promise<User | null> {
    const user = await this.getUserByUsername(username);
    if (!user) {
      return null;
    }

    const hashedPassword = await this.getHashedPassword(username);
    if (!hashedPassword) {
      return null;
    }

    const isMatch = await this.comparePasswords(password, hashedPassword);
    if (!isMatch) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Invalid credentials');
    }

    return user;
  }

  async comparePasswords(password, hashedPassword) {
    const isMatch = await compare(password, hashedPassword);
    return isMatch;
  }

  async getUserByUsername(username: string): Promise<User> {
    const user = await this.userRepository.findOne({ where: { username } });
    return user;
  }

  findOne(username: string): Promise<User> {
    return this.userRepository.findOne({ where: { username } });
  }
}
```

My Auth Module

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    UserModule,
    TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User]),
    PassportModule,
    JwtModule.register({
      global: true,
      secret: jwtConstants.secret,
      signOptions: { expiresIn: '60s' },
    }),
  ],
  providers: [
    AuthService,
    UserService,
    {
      provide: APP_GUARD,
      useClass: AuthGuard,
    },
  ],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

My Auth Controller

```
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(
    private readonly authService: AuthService,
    private readonly userService: UserService,
  ) {}

  @Public()
  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
  @Post('login')
  signIn(@Body() signInDto: Record<string, string>) {
    return this.authService.signIn(signInDto.username, signInDto.password);
  }

  @UseGuards(AuthGuard)
  @Get('profile')
  getProfile(@Request() req) {
    return req.user;
  }
}
```

and my auth guard

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private jwtService: JwtService, private reflector: Reflector) {}

  async canActivate(context: ExecutionContext): Promise<boolean> {
    const isPublic = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride<boolean>(IS_PUBLIC_KEY, [
      context.getHandler(),
      context.getClass(),
    ]);
    if (isPublic) {
      return true;
    }

    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const token = this.extractTokenFromHeader(request);
    if (!token) {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    try {
      const payload = await this.jwtService.verifyAsync(token, {
        secret: jwtConstants.secret,
      });
      request['user'] = payload;
    } catch {
      throw new UnauthorizedException();
    }
    return true;
  }

  private extractTokenFromHeader(request: Request): string | undefined {
    const [type, token] = request.headers.authorization?.split(' ') ?? [];
    return type === 'Bearer' ? token : undefined;
  }
}
```

anybody know how to fix ?

Comment: There's a few places that you end up throwing an `UnauthorizedException` and with no extra details it'll be almost impossible to determine which one was the issue